# Pthread return results

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a question about returning results from a pthread executed function.

Related code:

```
void* thread_func(void* args)
{
    float result = 0;
    // ...do something
    return (void*)&result;
}

// ... using code
float answer;
pthread_join(pthread_handle, &answer);
```

To me, this kind of solution doesn't seem like it should work safely because `result` would reside on the stack of `thread_func` and cease to exist after `thread_func` returns. However, in all the tests I've done it seems to work flawlessly. Is there something I'm misunderstanding about why this is safe? If not and my tests just happened to work due to some fluke, how do I safely get the return value back from `thread_func` safely?

Comment: It's definitely not OK, and most likely you simply haven't tested this very thoroughly. Try `valgrind` to start with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't safe. You simply got lucky (or rather unlucky). After the function ends all automatic variables are lost (thus pointers to them are useless).

- Use `malloc` and return that memory
- Use a static object (a global variable for instance)
- Use memory passed by the function that will join

In conclusion use some memory that will survive after the function ends.

Comment: In my calling code, would I call free(&answer)? Or would I also have to change it to float *answer, then call free(answer) when I'm done with the return result?

Comment: `free(&answer)` is **never** valid C. You would have to do the latter.

Comment: @helloworld922 Only call `free` on things obtained via `malloc`. The second alternative seems fine.